# run a JAVA program in the same command promp

Tags: java, command-prompt

I use the command prompt to run my JAVA program but when I run a .java file, another window is opened and closed quickly, I don't have the time to see the error,
here is my command :

```
start java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost
```

how can I do to resolve this problem
I tried :

```
start java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost -b
```

I found it in the help, but it does not work,

Comment: You can add > "pathtotextfile.txt" to output the standard output into a text file.

Answer (score 3):

You have to open two command prompt consoles, then type the commands you give without "start "

Answer (score 1):

Try

`start/b java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost`

Comment: thank you, it works, the error is now in the same command promp